# Check if boost rule has been applied to an item

Tags: content-search, azure-search, rules-engine

I am implementing functionality to push certain items in my content tree down in search results depending on a "discontinued" checkbox field. I have created a rule item under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Indexing and Search/Global Rules` which applies a negative boost value to items where the discontinued field is checked (== "1").

[image: Rule to negatively boost discontinued products]

Is there any way to tell from the documents in the search index to see that this negative boost value has been applied? I don't see any message about the execution of the rule in my crawling logs.

I am using Azure Search and have used Postman to inspect my index to look at the documents where I have checked the "discontinued" checkbox, but I don't see any difference. I noticed a `@search.score` property of the document but am not sure if this is related to the boost value applied to the document/item.

Comment: Have you rebuilt the index?

Comment: Yep. I did a full index rebuild.